# How do you trigger a gulp/grunt task on a remote server after deploy?

Tags: deployment, gruntjs, npm, gulp

I've just switched to Roots Sage starter theme for Wordpress: roots.io/sage/docs/
and I'm currently reading up on deployment processes.

My processes is usually:
- make changes
- build with grunt/gulp
- commit (including compiled scripts)
- deploy

Sage's .gitignore file removes the dist folder (compiled files) from the repo ie. no css/js in repo. Are you supposed to install node/npm and build the assets on staging/production environment after deploy? If so, how do you trigger a gulp/grunt task on a remote server after deploy?

I'm using https://www.springloops.com/ for managing git and deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you supposed to install node/npm and build the assets on staging/production environment after deploy?

You should avoid doing this. There is mixed opinion about committing compiled assets to a VCS as you stated you were doing previously, too.

Let's look at an example.

You finished all your testing locally. You haven't run an `npm update` in a few days and one of your dependencies has a loose version constraint specified; something like `"~1.0.0"`.

You deploy. On the server, `npm install` is run before `gulp` or `grunt`.  `gulp` runs, the build of your assets completes successfully, and the new version of your app is now live.

Unknown to you, version `1.0.1` of that dependency was released yesterday. For whatever reason, `1.0.1` introduced a change that breaks functionality within your app. **That breaking change is now live on your site in production.**

Even if you could guarantee all dependencies pulled from `npm install` on the server will mirror what you had locally/in staging, the headache of maintaining yet another set of software on the server (node.js, ruby, etc...) *just for compiling assets* should be enough to keep you from doing compilation on in production.

IMO, you should keep compiled assets out of your VCS, and rsync them to your server(s) as part of your deployment.

Comment: use 'npm shrinkwrap' to avoid being caught out by loose versioning